# Nextcloud with Docker Compose behind reverse proxy (nginx) with proxy_pass (leaking images)

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nextcloud, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Nextcloud running with the following docker-compose.yml file and I use Plesk with nginx as a reverse proxy.

My problem is that the images are accessible without a login.
I can open a image with the following url `https://nc.mydomain.com/core/preview?fileId=30&x=2880&y=1800&a=true`

I tried the nginx directives from the Nextcloud docker-compose example on [Github](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/master/.examples/docker-compose/insecure/mariadb/fpm/web/nginx.conf).
Problem here is it does not work, because i have to use `proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080/;`

Can someone help, to prevent accessing the images without the login?

- make the [nginx settings](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/master/.examples/docker-compose/insecure/mariadb/fpm/web/nginx.conf) work with proxy_pass, but how.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE=1
      - MARIADB_DISABLE_UPGRADE_BACKUP=1
    env_file:
      - db.env
    volumes:
      - volumes/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: nextcloud-redis
    restart: always
    command: /bin/sh -c "redis-server --requirepass $$REDIS_HOST_PASSWORD"
    env_file:
      - redis.env

  app:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:80
    volumes:
      - volumes/nextcloud:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=nc.mydomain.com
    env_file:
      - db.env
      - redis.env

  cron:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    container_name: nextcloud-cron
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - volumes/nextcloud:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: /cron.sh
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

volumes:
  db:
  nextcloud:
```

"Additional nginx directives" in the Plesk settings for the Nextcloud Subdomain (leaking images).

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header    Host $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
  #Only use secure connection
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
  #Allow big files to upload
  client_max_body_size 0;
}

location /.well-known/carddav {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
}

location /.well-known/caldav {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The browser cached the image.**
That's why it was possible to open the image without login to Nextcloud.

Open the URL `https://nc.mydomain.com/core/preview?fileId=30&x=2880&y=1800&a=true` in a different Browser, or clear the cache after logout and the images was not accessible anymore.